# ESlint cannot find a babel config file with a relative path

Tags: babeljs, eslint

In a JavaScript project I have an .eslintrc.yml file side-by-side with a .babelrc.json config file. The babel config is included in the eslint file so:

```yaml
parserOptions:
  sourceType: module
  project: ['./tsconfig.json']
  ecmaVersion: 2022
  babelOptions:
    configFile: ".babelrc.json"
```

though ESlint reports an error it cannot find that config file (`Parsing error: Cannot find module '.babelrc.json'`). When I use an absolute path to the config file, then it works. I tried `./.babelrc.json`, but that didn't work either. How are relative paths resolved in ESlint? I would expect that it resolves the babel config relative to the eslint config file.

The setup for that project is a bit unusual, because it is part of a larger git repository  and just one subfolder of many. So the config files are not at the root of the git repo.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems like the current directory is just not being properly set by babel. Setting the `root` or `cwd` to the current directory's absolute path also works.